# Iterating through a yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to iterate through a yaml file. I want to extract the contents
ipv6: "2031:31:31:31:: 2032:32:32:32:: 2033:33:33:33:: 2034:34:34:34:: 2035:35:35:35::"
Below is my code. I get the below error :

```
 for x in self.dhcp_dict['subnets'][sub]['ipv4'].split():
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Can anyone tell em where i am going wrong? Thanks
Jessi
Code:

```
dict = yaml.load(fd)
        self.server_dict = dict['server_configs']
        self.interface_dict = self.server_dict['interface']
        self.dhcp_dict = self.server_dict['dhcp_config']


def configureDhcpv6(self):
        pdb.set_trace()
        log.info ("Writing the dhcp.conf file")
        infile = open('v6.txt', 'w+')

        self.lease_time = self.dhcp_dict['lease_time']
        infile.write("default-lease-time %s; \n" %(self.lease_time))
        infile.write("preferred-lifetime 604800;\noption dhcp-renewal-time 604800;\noption dhcp-rebinding-time 7200;\noption dhcp6.domain-search cisco.com;\noption dhcp6.preference 255;\noption dhcp6.rapid-commit;\noption dhcp6.info-refresh-time 21600;\ndhcpv6-lease-file-name /var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd6.leases;\nauthoritative;\nlog-facility local7;\n\n")

        for sub in self.dhcp_dict['subnets']:
            if (sub == 'relay'):
                 for x in self.dhcp_dict['subnets'][sub]['ipv6'].split():
                     range6 = sub + "11" + " " + sub + "254"
                     infile.write("Subnet 6  %s/64 {\n" % (sub))
                     infile.write("        range6 %s;\n}\n\n" % (range6))

        infile.close()
```

Yaml file:

```
dhcp_config:
    lease_time: "300"
    relay_server: "5.5.5.0"
    subnets:
      relay:
        ipv4: "30.30.30.0 31.31.31.0 32.32.32.0 33.33.33.0 34.34.34.0 35.35.35.0"
        ipv6: "2031:31:31:31:: 2032:32:32:32:: 2033:33:33:33:: 2034:34:34:34:: 2035:35:35:35::"
      smart_relay: "31.1.1.0 32.1.1.0 33.1.1.0 34.1.1.0 35.1.1.0"
      snoop: "36.36.36.0 37.37.37.0 38.38.38.0 39.39.39.0 30.30.30.0"
```

Comment: Not sure what's the point of the outer loop, if you just want the relay key. Why not directly do `self.dhcp_dict['subnets']['relay']['ipv6']`?

Comment: The outer loop is to get the individual ipv6 address - 2031:31:31:31:: 2032:32:32:32:: 2033:33:33:33:: 2034:34:34:34:: 2035:35:35:35:: I am splitting the string and extracting the addresses.. but that is where I am getting the error i think

Comment: That's the inner loop. You can do that split without iterating over the keys inside subnets, since you only want one.

Comment: I modified the code as below, to remove the outer loop, i still get the same erro

Comment: for x in self.dhcp_dict['subnets']['relay']['ipv6'].split():
            range6 = x + "11" + " " + x + "254"
            infile.write("Subnet 6  %s/64 {\n" % (x))
            infile.write("        range6 %s;\n}\n\n" % (range6))

Comment: The error message is not from the code shown. It complains about a line with `'ipv4'` in it, yours has `'ipv6'`. Also, the code shown is not formatted correctly and seems to miss a `class` definition. Finally, you assign the loaded YAML to `dict`, which is a Python core class. This may lead to unforseen consequences and is very bad style.

Comment: I figured what the mistake is.. The yaml file was not saved properly.. its working.. thanks a lot